# Cauchy integral and residue theorem

Tags: cauchy-integral-formula

What is the difference in terms of the physical meaning of the two sets of the following Cauchy integral,
$$
\begin{split}
\int_c t^k \cdot \frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta} \frac{dt}{t} &=4\pi i \zeta^k\\
\int_c \frac{1}{t^k} \cdot \frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta} \frac{dt}{t} &=0
\end{split}
$$
from G. N. SAVIN (1968), *[Stress Distribution around Holes](https://archive.org/details/nasa_techdoc_19710000647)*, NASA Technical Translation,
with respect to this one
$$
\begin{split}
\int_c t^k \cdot \frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta} \frac{dt}{t} &= 0\\
\int_c \frac{1}{t^k} \cdot \frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta} \frac{dt}{t} &=\frac{4\pi i}{\zeta^k}
\end{split}
$$

from V. G. UKADGAONKER and V. KAKHANDKI 2005. "Stress analysis for an orthotropic plate with an irregular shaped hole for different in-plane loading conditions—Part 1". Composite Structures, 70, 255-274.

In both cases $k \geq 1$ and $c$ is a unit circle. Also, in both cases, $\zeta^k = e^{k \theta i} = \cos k \theta + i \sin k \theta$

What consideration does each author perhaps used so that they came up with a slightly "opposite" relations? Is it something to do with the "internal region" or "external region" integration around the boundary?

Comment: Roughly speaking, may be in one of them $k>0$ while in the other $k<0$...

Comment: Thanks. What consideration does each author perhaps used so that they came up with a slightly "opposite" relations? Is it something to do with the "internal region" or "external region" integration around the boundary?

Comment: Well. The reason I think, is more practical than mathematical. May be one was dealing more with negative $k$s and the other cared the positive cases. I mention, these are all just guesses.

Comment: I have added another basic assumption for the equations, that in both cases $k \geq 1$

Comment: Is $C$ explicitly defined? e.g. unit circle?

Comment: Yes. That's right. $C$ is a unit circle.

Comment: One more question: what about $|\zeta|$?

Comment: It is defined as $\zeta = e^{k \theta i} = \cos k \theta + i \sin k \theta$

Comment: If $|\zeta| < 1$ and the integral is taken in the ccw direction in the first two formulas and $|\zeta| > 1$ and the integral is taken in the cw direction in the last two formulas, then both sets of formulas are correct. If $|\zeta| = 1$, as $\zeta^k = e^{i k \theta}$ implies, then the formulas are not correct, even if you take the Cauchy principal value.

Comment: Does it mean that the first two formulae integrate a region "inside" the circle $c$ while the last two formulae integrate a region "outside" the circle?